# Extjs 4.2.2 - Default sorter logic runs instead of custom sorter

Tags: sorting, extjs, datagrid, extjs4.2

On ExtJs 4.2.2 I need to override default sorter of some column and make it sort by the absolute values (Math.abs).

When I debug it I get into doSort() and get the right store & direction (asc, desc), but for some reason it doesn't execute rthe sorterFn() - and run the default sorter (I know it cause nothing is printed to console, and the behaviour in client is the default)

```
{
            itemId:  someId,
            //header: 'Abs. Change',


            menuDisabled: false,
            dataIndex: 'AbsChange',

            sortable: true,
            renderer: this.absChangeLabelRenderer,
            width: 95,
            align: 'right',

            doSort: function (state) {
                debugger;
                var ds = this.up('tablepanel').store;
                var field = this.getSortParam();
                ds.sort({
                    property: field,
                    direction: state,
                    sorterFn: function (v1, v2) {
                        debugger;
                        console.log("value1 is {0}, value2 is {1}", v1, v2);

                        debugger;
                        v1 = Math.abs(v1.get(field));
                        v2 = Math.abs(v2.get(field));
                        // transform v1 and v2 here
                        return v1 > v2 ? 1 : (v1 < v2 ? -1 : 0);
                    }
                });
            }               
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the [`sortType`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.3/#!/api/Ext.data.Field-cfg-sortType) configuration in your model's field definition, i.e. a function that returns the value used for sorting.

Example configuration:

```
fields: [
    // ... other fields ...
    {
        name: 'AbsChange',
        sortType: function(value) {
            return Math.abs(value);
        }
    }
]
```

Comment: my issue was that my store already had sorter which overriden my code above :) - anyway this answer is neat anyway